# Unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 on system with Windows 10

Tags: grub2, uefi, windows

I've recently purchased a Dell Vostro 3500 with Windows 10 pre-installed. It is a UEFI system. I don't want to keep Windows 10 and I want to replace it with Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the regular method as follows:

1. Created a live USB for Ubuntu
2. Changed boot order in BIOS to boot it from the live USB (a note: for some reason it showed two different options in BIOS; both are my live USB)
3. Let the disk check happen to ensure there were no errors

Then the installation process started. At the "Updates and Software" stage, it simply said that Ubuntu requires 8.6 GB of space while my system has only 8.1. It gave no options to continue forward to the point where it gives installation options (installing alongside Windows, erasing it, or something else).

What do I do here? Almost all tutorials online say that this is how it is supposed to be done and I can't find any other instances of someone facing this problem.

Comment: If you want to get rid of Windows and use Ubuntu instead, you should select the option to erase the disk. If you aren't getting that option, choose "Try Ubuntu" from installation media for a live session. Then use the "Disks" app to format (erase) your hard drive and use the GPT partition scheme. Then you have an empty disk for an easy guided installation

Comment: The reason there are two options when booting is because one is for UEFI and the other is for BIOS/compatibility. If you have a GPT disk, choose the UEFI option

Comment: If you're getting disk space errors, you probably didn't install Ubuntu correctly. The biggest mistake that many users make is to completely get rid of Windows. Best to reinstall Windows and then install Ubuntu "along side of Windows" for a dual-boot configuration.

Comment: @Nmath Unfortunately, Gparted from the live USB doesn't show any disks or partitions apart from the USB drive itself. So I can't wipe the Windows parition from here. Is there another way to do that? Also, is there a way I can check which boot option on the live USB is for UEFI compatibility?

Comment: I suggested that you use "Disks". What was the result?  If you've been using Windows you will need to turn off "fast startup" in Windows before shutting down, or else Windows won't actually shut down, but it will be suspended and resources will be locked.

Comment: It's the same result with Disks as well, even after turning off fast startup in Windows. Not sure if it is relevant, but I checked the Disk Management tool on Windows and my hard disk is BitLocker encrypted. Could that be causing it? If so, how do I remove that encryption?

Comment: The Ubuntu installer doesn't know what to do with BitLocker encrypted partitions. I can't help with BitLocker, but maybe `man bitlocker` will help. The biggest reason to keep Windows, ie: dual-boot, is to do BIOS updates, or to run any Windows-only apps that don't have Linux counterparts. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to find your current BIOS version, then go to the Dell web site and check for a newer BIOS. **CAREFULLY** read the installation instructions, as there's an important note about suspending BitLocker before performing any BIOS update.

Comment: On my system, searching for BitLocker points to Device Encryption. I turned this off and now in Disk Management, C: is no longer encrypted by BitLocker. But I'm still facing the same issue with the Ubuntu live USB. On top of that, when I go to my Microsoft account, it says that the BitLocker encryption for my device is on. But even checking via Command Prompt using `manage-bde` shows that encryption is off and files are unlocked. And there's no GUI for BitLocker. When I click on that option in settings, the settings window just shuts down. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: There is still no solution to this. I've checked my Microsoft account and now even that confirms that BitLocker protection is off. But the live USB still won't see my hard disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a [solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045&page=2) to this. Ubuntu 20.04 does not support 11th generation processors. The problem goes away if you try with 21.04. I'm assuming it's a kernel issue so even 20.04.3 should work when it comes out, in case anyone wants only LTS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check your disks partitions in windows. Do you have a partition that has 8.1Gb free space and another with windows installed on it? I have found that the installer will not install over the top of the partition with windows (not while choosing default options anyway). If so, you can delete the windows partition or shrink it to provide adequate space for ubuntu install (if you want dual boot) using the Disk Management utility.

Comment: You DON'T want to delete the Windows partition, and you DO want to create a dual-boot configuration.

Comment: @heynnema I would request you to read my whole query before responding. I wrote that I wasn't able to install Ubuntu so the question of "installing Ubuntu correctly" or of "reinstalling Windows" doesn't arise as my Windows install is intact. And I'm not looking for recommendations on whether I should or shouldn't wipe Windows. I've had a dual boot system for 8 years and I've seen no benefits. If you can list out some of them, that would be great.